# Is there a way to add a CSS ID to R FastRWeb otable() output so that it can be formatted using DatablesJS?

Tags: r, rcloud

[DataTables JS requires a well formatted HTML table that includes a table id and a  tag](https://datatables.net/manual/installation).

Is it possible to add these to the FastRWeb otable() output so that the output can be formatted using DataTables JS?  I am calling this using the RCloud notebook.R web service interface so I need to use the FastRWeb library.

I tried adding an out() before the table:

```
library(FastRWeb)
run <- function(...) {
    out("<thead><tr><th>Column 1:</th><th>Column 2:</th></tr></thead>")
    d <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c("foo", "bar", "foobar"))
    otable(d)
    done()
 }
```

However, that creates another table on top of the otable().

Comment: Why not use DT?

Comment: I am calling a notebook.R notebook.

Comment: I see! Glad you figured it out!

Comment: FWIW I think you can also use htmlwidgets in notebook.R apps (just print the widget), so at least the pure client-side DT should also work. The iframe might make it a bit heavier / clumsier though.

Answer (score 1):

This works for a RCloud notebook.R notebook:

```
library(knitr)
run <- function(...) {
  x = kable(mtcars, format = 'html',  table.attr = 'id=\'mytable\'')
  out(x)
  done()
}
```